# SQL query for list($order_total, $order_id) = mysqli_fetch_array($r); is successful but bugged

Tags: php, mysql

I realize a lot of this code is hand waving and show off, and I don't take credit for that. The code successfully executes all the query except the vairable I created for order_id is not returned when I try to show the receipt page with the order_id.

Option 1: Realize that procedures are just functions and rewrite them for debugging

Option 2: Fix the return mysqli_fetch to get the newly created order_id.

So let's start from the beginning of the procedure:
Customer enters Infromation and passes that to procedure add_customer

I save the infromation and then use that customer_id to create a unique order with call add_order

then When I try to get the order Id to create a an email receipt there seems to be a major bug that is unfixable because I have never seen a fetch returned as a list of two variables

```
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, "CALL add_customer('$e', '$fn', '$ln', '$a1', '$a2', '$c', '$s', $z, $p, @cid)");

            // Confirm that it worked:

            if ($r) {
                mysqli_stmt_execute($r);
                echo 'success';
                //Retrieve the customer ID:
                $r = mysqli_query($dbc, 'SELECT @cid');
                //Select the new customer ID
                if (mysqli_num_rows($r) == 1) {

                    list($_SESSION['customer_id']) = mysqli_fetch_array($r);
                    //$cc_last_four = substr($cc_number, -4);
                    $cc_last_four = 1234;
                    // Call the stored procedure:

                    $shipping = $_SESSION['shipping'] * 100;
                    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, "CALL add_order({$_SESSION['customer_id']}, '$uid', $shipping, $cc_last_four, @total, @oid)");

                    echo "success Customer ID to add_order";
                    //select Order ID
                    if ($r) {

                        // Retrieve the order ID and total:
                        $r = mysqli_query($dbc, 'SELECT @total, @oid');
                        if (mysqli_num_rows($r) == 1) {
                            list($order_total, $order_id) = mysqli_fetch_array($r);
                            echo "Order ID Found";
                            echo $order_id;
                            // Store the information in the session:
                            $_SESSION['order_total'] = $order_total;
                            $_SESSION['order_id'] = $order_id;
                            echo $_SESSION['order_total'],
                            $_SESSION['order_id'];
                            // Redirect to the next page:
                            include_once("includes/email_receipt.php");
```

successsuccess Customer ID to add_orderOrder ID Found

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: The only thing this code is showing off is that someone really loves stored procedures and really doesn't care about modern best practices. It might look impressive but in actuality it's really anything but.

Comment: Right the most modern practice is model view controller which is just a bunch of procedures.

Comment: It's not just a bunch of procedures. It's a philosophy for organizing code, something this particular sample seems allergic to.

Answer (score 0):

OKAY ILL TRY TO BE QUICK AND QUIT BEATING AROUND THE BUSH

Procedute Add_To_order changed to

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE subtotal INT(10);
    INSERT INTO orders (customer_id, shipping, credit_card_number, order_date) VALUES (cid, ship, cc, NOW());
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO oid;

END
```

And the code changed to

```
                    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, 'SELECT @oid');
                    if (mysqli_num_rows($r) == 1) {
                        list($order_id) = mysqli_fetch_array($r);
                        echo "Order ID Found";
                        echo $order_id;
                        // Store the information in the session:
                        $_SESSION['order_total'] = $order_total;
                        $_SESSION['order_id'] = $order_id;
                        echo $_SESSION['order_total'],
                        $_SESSION['order_id'];
                        // Redirect to the next page:
                        include_once("includes/email_receipt.php");
```